Finding $\mathbb{E}[\max(|\xi - \eta|,|\xi - ζ|,|\eta - ζ|)]$
$\xi, \eta, ζ$ - independent random variables uniformly distributed on the interval [0, 1]. Using conditional expected value, find $\mathbb{E}[\max(|\xi - \eta|,|\xi - ζ|,|\eta - ζ|)]$
Here what I got: $$
\mathbb{E}[\max(|\xi - \eta|,|\xi - ζ|,|\eta - ζ|)] = \int_\mathbb{R^3} \max(|x - y|,|x - z|,|y - z|)  p_{\xi}(x)  p_{\eta}(y)  p_{ζ}(z)dxdydz
$$
Then I took the first case : $|x-y| > |x-z|, |x-y| > |y-z|$ and got
$\max(|x - y|,|x - z|,|y - z|) = (x-y)$ if $y<z<x$ and $\max(|x - y|,|x - z|,|y - z|) = (y-x)$ if $x<z<y$.
Then I calculated $\int^1_\mathbb{0}\int^x_\mathbb{0}\int^z_\mathbb{0}(x-y)dydzdx = 1/12$ (Same for $(y-x)$). Another two cases seem similar, so the answer is $(1/12 + 1/12) * 3) = 1/2$. Is everything alright?

Note that $\xi,\eta,\zeta$ are three points on $[0,1]$ so
$$
Z=\max(|\xi - \eta|,|\xi - \zeta|,|\eta - \zeta|)
$$
is just the distance between the leftmost and the rightmost point of the three.

Hence
$$
Z=X_{\max}-X_{\min}
$$
where $X_\max=\max(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ and $X_\min=\min(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$.
Now trivially $\mathbb{P}(X_\max\le a)=a^3$, $a\in [0,1]$ from which you get the density of $X_\max$ by differentiating w.r.t. $a$, so
$$
\mathbb{E}X_\max=\int_0^1 a\cdot 3a^2da=\frac{3}{4}.
$$
By symmetry around $1/2$, $\mathbb{E}X_\min=1-\mathbb{E}X_\max=\frac14$ so
$$
\mathbb{E}Z=\mathbb{E}X_\max-\mathbb{E}X_\min=\frac12.
$$

I'm sorry, can I ask why $\mathbb{P}(X_\max\le a)=a^3$?

$\Pr(X_{\max} \leq a) = \Pr({\xi \leq a} \cap {\eta \leq a} \cap {\zeta \leq a})$. Use independence to conclude.
